# Should I dereference local scoped objects?

Tags: javascript

I've made a research but I couldn't find the answer to my question. There is written that to avoid memory leakage I should dereference global scoped variables like this:

```
let object1 = {};
// use object
object1 = null;
```

But what if an object is created inside a function:

```
function() {
  let object1 = {}
}
```

or

```
(function() {
  let object1 = {}
})()
```

Should I dereference these objects inside those examples or the garbage collector takes care about it?

Comment: If there are no more references to the object, it's eligible for garbage collection. After the function finishes executing, the variable is removed and it no longer counts as a reference to the object. If you have no other references (e.g., you haven't stored that object anywhere globally), then it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Setting something to `null` is not what "dereference" means

Comment: @Bergi, can u explain me please?